# C++ How to use std::sort with comparator based on your class' function

Tags: c++, sorting

Im trying to sort my vector depending on value returned by function calculateDistance() which returns double value. I guess the problem is caused by permutationCopmarator method. .cpp file looks like this:

```
bool TSPgenetic::permutationComparator(int* i, int* j){
  return calculateDistance(i) < calculateDistance(j);
}

void TSPgenetic::chooseNewPopulation(){

  sort(population->begin(), population->end(), permutationComparator);
  sort(children->begin(), children->end(), permutationComparator);

`....`

}
```

Header file fragment:

```
bool permutationComparator(int*, int*);
```

Comment: What problem do you have with this?

Comment: Why do you have a vector of *pointers* to integers? And why are you heap allocating it? And why are you sorting the same range with the same operator *twice*?

Comment: Im sorry, forgot to write, 
Error C3867 'TSPgenetic::permutationComparator': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member;

Comment: And did you try doing what the error said?

Comment: @NicolBolas, im using it later, the problem is only with sorting, ill edit code now

Comment: @NathanOliver, well i spend like an hour on this and I cant fix it

Comment: Make `permutationComparator` static and and pass a pointer of it: `&TSPgenetic::permutationComparator`

Answer (score 1):

Passing `permutationComparator` as the third parameter of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is not valid. Only `static` class members is valid and functor objects. To resolve the issue, here's four choices:

- Create a closure object using [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and do your comparison there.

  ```
  std::sort(population->begin(), population->end(), [](const int *i1, const int *i2){return calculateDistance(i1) < calculateDistance(i2);});
  ```
- You can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), if your comparsion function needs not to be `static`.

  ```
  auto comp_func = std::bind(&TSPgenetic::permutationComparator, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
  std::sort(population->begin(), population->end(), comp_func);
  ```
- Make your comparison function `static`, if it's possible.
- Overload `bool operator () ( const int *i1, const int *i2 )` in your class in order that your class to be a [functor object](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html).

Note that logically a comparison function should not to be a member function. It is a function that takes two objects and determines their orders. So, almost in all cases, only the **third option** applies.

Comment: or just make the function static if possible.